# Detect if a received email has been sent from a specific "mailto" link

Tags: html, email, mailto

I would like to know, when I receive an email to my personal address "contact@MySite.com", if the sender wrote me from my website "MySite.com" clicking the "mailto" link or not. 
In principle I can just add the "Subject" tag to the mailto scheme but the user can delete it and anyway I don't want it to be visible. 
I thought I could add custom header tags and I tried the following:

```
<a href="mailto:contact@MySite.com?X-Mailer=FromMyWebsite">
        <span class="label">Contact me </span>
        <span class="strap">Send me an email</span>
</a>
```

and I tried it. The email I received contained "X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1510)" in the header. I thought that my email client replaced the X-Mailer tag and I added a custom one, like following:

```
<a href="mailto:contact@MySite.com?X-Origin=FromMyWebsite">
        <span class="label">Contact me </span>
        <span class="strap">Send me an email</span>
</a>
```

but the header of the email didn't contain any X-Origin field. 
Am I doing something wrong? How can I know if an email has been sent from my mailto link or not keeping it hidden to the sender?
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I have no idea whether this is possible - my suspicion is it isn't - but *if* you're going to try it, the right way would be `X-Origin=FromMyWebsite`

Comment: Since this is all client side code, it's pretty much irrelevant since the user could change any of it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't know why the colon came up in my question, but there is no colon in the html code. Io edited the question.

Comment: @j08691 when I say that the user can change it, I mean that if I write something like 
    <a href="mailto:contact@MySite.com?Subject=FromMyWebsite">
        <span class="label">Contact me </span>
        <span class="strap">Send me an email</span>
</a>
after clicking the email client will open with the subject field filled with "FromMyWebsite" text, but the user can easily change it.

Comment: I understand, however since this is all client side code, anyone can tweak what you deliver and change it. Not that anyone would bother, but it's entirely possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to set header information this way. It also arguably shouldn't be possible in the first place.

If this information is really so important to you, a better way to do this might be (mis)using the *recipient* address. Say you use an address like

```
contact.website@example.com
```

this method is

- 100% compatible with all E-Mail clients
- hard for the user to change (as they can't be sure whether their message will arrive if they do)
- infinitely extensible - you could go as far as storing information about the user's visit in a database, and send a random ID in the E-Mail through which you can connect the web site visit to the E-Mail:

  ```
  contact.website.1ahGfd23@example.com
  ```

Comment: This is definitely a possible solution, but not very elegant since I will have to create an alias for every origin I want to track. But more important is that if the user will add me to his Contacts, he will add an alias that I may want to delete in the future.

Comment: @Alain you wouldn't necessarily have to create aliases if your server is equipped to either catch all messages to a domain (which brings spam problems though) or do it like Google mail, accepting a format like `contact+website@example.com` and interpreting it as `contact@example.com`. That would take some effort to set up. Either way - I don't see any other way to do what you want to achieve, it's either this or the subject or the body.

Comment: I tried what you said, adding "myemail+something@domain.com" and it worked.
Could you explain me why? Is it a desired behavior that "myemail+something@domain.com" is interpreted as "myemail@domain.com"? Which is the reason?

Comment: Additionally, is it a safe technique or I'll have unexpected behaviors?

Comment: @Alain1405 I don't know exactly whether this is coded in the specs or a side-effect. With Google Mail, it seems to be fixed and is used regularly, but I can't say what it's like for non-Google servers

Comment: I finally was able to find something about it. It is called "plus addressing" and is a feature of many email services. Thanks!

Comment: What I do is set `?subject=:` at the end for 3 reasons. 1. It avoids a no-subject email. 2. The probability that the person will delete the  colon (:) character is very low, and as such is good identifier that the email was sent from the website, when the subject starts with `:`. 3. You can also add different subjects before the colon as a way to target and identify different page contexts, and/or re-route that email based on the subject.